# Redis se conecta y después se desconecta del servidor

Tags: python, base-de-datos, redis

Estoy usando Redis para una aplicacion que estoy desarrollando en Python. A esta aplicacion la compilo en .exe y luego la ejecuto, pero para que funcione necesito a Redis, pero mi idea es no instalar a Redis cada vez que quiera usar la aplicacion en Python, si no crear un servidor 127.0.0.1:6379 para poder usar Redis independientemente del instalador de Redis.
He creado servidorres locales con Python, hasta con node.js con express, pero en todos obtengo el mismo resultado, una desconexion de la aplicacion por que sale este error de Redis:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rescript.py", line 165, in <module>
    "CODUNIDAD":i[73]})
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\redis\client.py", line 1905, in hmset
    return self.execute_command('HMSET', name, *items)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\redis\client.py", line 579, in execute_command
    return self.parse_response(connection, command_name, **options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\redis\client.py", line 585, in parse_response
    response = connection.read_response()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\redis\connection.py", line 577, in read_response
    response = self._parser.read_response()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\redis\connection.py", line 238, in read_response
    response = self._buffer.readline()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\redis\connection.py", line 168, in readline
    self._read_from_socket()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\redis\connection.py", line 143, in _read_from_socket
    (e.args,))
redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error while reading from socket: ('Connection closed by server.',)
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrías usar docker, creas el contenedor una vez, y luego solo lo levantas(o inicias)

```
docker pull redis (baja la imagen)
docker run --name redis-t -t -d -p 6379:6379 redis (creas el contenedor)
docker start redis-t (lo inicias)
```

(Necesitas instalar docker en Windows)